# conn.query() method is not returning all the records

Tags: soql, salesforcedx, query, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to create a custom sfdx plugin, for that I am fetching a query result using

> const result = await connection.query(SOQLQuery);

but it is not giving me all the records which are present in my salesforce org instead it is showing me this

[image]

because of this I am not getting the records which are needed.

Am I missing out on something?

Can we make changes in predefined query() method??

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. What library are you using? Are you sure it's not just a console.log limitation? Does the library expect you to call queryMore or use the nextRecordsUrl property of the response to get more records? Please be as detailed as possible so we can help you.

Comment: I am using const conn = this.org.getConnection(); and in this conn there is a method called autoFetchQuery() method if use this method I am able to get my desired results. Many Thanks.